Writing functions horizontally error
I have been trying to define two functions horizontally in latex using align*, flalign*, aligned etc. All manner of permutations of these. I can't seem to get it to work or rid myself of an error. Even this basic code now is not working and driving me mad. Any help would be much appreciated.
\begin{align*}
\phi^{\smll}= 
\begin{cases}
    \phi(x),& \text{when }  \phi(x)\in [-2,2]\\
    0,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}

&& 
\phi^{\bg}= 
\begin{cases}
    0,& \text{when }  \phi(x)\in [-2,2]\\
    \phi(x),              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}


Please try to make your question clear and simple by providing a minimal working example.

please  provide an example  not just a fragment, and also show the error that you get. Note that you can not have blank lines in the source for displayed equations. If I guess a preamble then I get errors for the blank line and the undefined commands \smll and \bg

Since your objective is to generate a single (logical) row of displayed math, there's no justification or satisfactory reason for using an align* environment -- which, after all, is designed to be used in multi-row settings. Instead, use an equation* environment or, equivalently, \[ ... \].

\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'cases' env.
\providecommand\smll{\textup{smll}} % ?
\providecommand\bg{\textup{bg}}     % ?

\begin{document}

\[
\phi^{\smll}= 
\begin{cases}
    \phi(x) & \textup{if $\phi(x) \in [-2,2]$,}\\
    0       & \textup{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\qquad
\phi^{\bg}= 
\begin{cases}
    0       & \textup{if $\phi(x) \in [-2,2]$,}\\
    \phi(x) & \textup{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\]

\end{document}

